# Find sum of subset with multiplication

Tags: algorithm, sum, subset, multiplication, subset-sum

Let's say we have got a set

```
{a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n}
```

The goal is to find a sum that we create in the following way: We find all subsets whose length is 3, then multiply each subset's elements (for the subset `{b_1, b_2, b_3}` the result will be `b_1*b_2*b_3`). At the end we sum up all these products.

I am looking for a shortest time-execution algorithm.

Example

```
SET: {3, 2, 1, 2}

Let S be our sum.

S = 3*2*1 + 3*2*2 + 2*1*2 + 3*1*2 = 28
```

Comment: `{3, 2, 1, 2}` is not a *set*. It's a *multiset* / *bag*

Comment: @amit From the problem it seems that it is supposed to be treated as a set.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Don't think so - he counts 2 twice, the number of occurances of each element is important - while in a *set* - there are no repeats.

Comment: @amit yes so they are treated like 4 different elements as in a unique set in (4C3) ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to calculate sum of multiplied triplets when repetitions are allowed (like a_1*a_1*a_1). This sum is just `(sum^3)`.

Since repetitions are not allowed, we could just subtract them: `(sum^3 - 3*sumsquares*sum)`.

But the above formula subtracts elements on main diagonal 3 times while it should be subtracted only once. Need to compensate this: `(sum^3 - 3*sumsquares*sum + 2*sumcubes)`.

The above formula does not take into account 3! permutations of each triplet. So it should be divided by `3!`.

Finally we have a linear-time algorithm:

1. Compute sum of given multiset elements, sum of squares, sum of cubes.
2. `result = (sum^3 - 3*sumsquares*sum + 2*sumcubes)/6`

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your answer. In the expansion of (a+b+c)^3 there are terms like (a^2)*b also. How does your formula subtract those terms?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: It's easier to explain this for subsets of length 2 (pairs). We could write products of all possible pairs as a matrix. Then to get proper sum we could add together all elements above (or below) main diagonal. Complexity is O(N^2). Alternatively we could add together each row (which gives a_i*sum), then add together all these sums (which gives sum^2), then remove elements of main diagonal and divide by 2. Now complexity is O(N). What I proposed is just generalization of this approach to subsets of length 3.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an `O(n^2)` approach:

```
sum = SUM(list)
answer = 0
for each i from 0 to n:
   sum -= list[i]
   remains = sum
   for each j from i+1 to n:
      remains -= list[j]
      answer += list[i] * list[j] * (remains)
```

It works because for each two elements `x,y` you need to sum `x*y*z` (for all elements `z`), but the sum of all possible `z` values is `SUM(list) - x - y`.

So, instead of doing: `x*y*z1 + x*y*z2 + ... + x*y*z(n-2)` , you basically do `x*y*(z1 + ... + z(n-2))`

**EDIT:** Editted multi-counting due to not multiplying only in the 'tail', as mentioned by @AbhishekBansal . You need to multiply each element only with the 'tail' of the list, where the tail is all the elements after the last element among `x,y`.

Comment: On second thoughts I somehow think it may have duplicacies.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal TBH, I am not sure (after re-reading) what the OP really wants, his example adds 3*2*1 and 3*1*2, but counts 3*2*2 only once.

Comment: Aah yes you are right. BTW for unique set is my implementation of your idea correct?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal No, I commented on your post.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear because you can choose 3 elements out of 4 different elements in 4 possible ways. The OP is doing just that. Moreover, I still think that your solution is over-counting.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yea, you are right, you need to multiply only in the 'tail'.. joined forces to get optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Full Working Code in C++ (Following up on Amit's idea)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s[] = {3, 2, 1, 2};

    double sumOfFullList = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        sumOfFullList += s[i];

    double sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      double sumOfList = sumOfFullList - s[i];
      sumOfFullList -= s[i];
      for ( int j = i+1; j < 4; j++ ) {
          sumOfList -= s[j];
          sum += s[i]*s[j]*(sumOfList);
          //cout << s[i] << " " << s[j] << " " << sumOfList;
      }
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
28
```

Comment: Note that assuming all positive numbers, `sumOfList` will quickly go negative