# How to count combinations from many types?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

I need to create a function which allow me to count combinations without repetition from many types.

Example
Calculate 3-elements combinations using 4 types:

**A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 C1 D1**

In every combination types cannot repeat:

**A1 B1 C1** is *correct*, but 
**A1 A2 B1** is *wrong*.

Having given the number of items of each type must calculate the number of combinations without repetition.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: @Ben: So far my only idea was to calculate them with a triple loop.

Comment: That'll work for 3-tuples, but not for arbitrary tuples. Google "enumerating combinations" to get an idea of how you can do this without hardcoding the tuple size.

Comment: @Ben: The point is that I have to calculate combinations only for 3-tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First choose the 3 types from which you will choose the elements. This can be done in NC3 ways where N is the number of types.

For each of these combinations, the number of possible ways = n1*n2*n3 where n1, n2, n3 are the number of elements of type 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

```
Hence, Count = summation(ni*nj*nk) {i,j,k = 1 to N}
```

This is actually identical to this question that is already solved: [Find sum of subset with multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723575/find-sum-of-subset-with-multiplication/19723723#19723723)